# How to mark folder as resource root in Visual Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpstorm

In PhpStorm I can set Directories Marking:

[image: Directories Marking]

Wonder if I can find setting to do so in VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a year since posted, but I ran into this exact problem. There's no UI for it, but you can solve it using jsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "assets/*": [
        "./assets/*" // <-- relative to baseURL, so it will resolve to ./src/assets/*
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

with this configuration, you can now do this: `import foo from 'assets/file.png`
you'll obviously need to configure webpack, browisfy or whatever to also understand this path

Answer (score -3):

I dont think that is possible from plain VS Code but might be possible due to extensions like [vs-codeicons](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=robertohuertasm.vscode-icons) is changing what files and folders look like there might be an extension that can do what you want.

You just need to do some research to figure that out.

Comment: No problem with the icon. I used [Material Icon Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PKief.material-icon-theme) extension for my VS Code.

I want to [Configuring Folders Within a Content Root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html#d128335e7) just like PhpStorm have.